# My iPhone storage only has 16gb but i buy 50gb iCloud storage

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

Is there any way that i could store stuff on the iCloud and not have it stored on the phone storage? Coz i feel like i bought the iCloud storage for nothing because the stuff i could put in the iCloud storage doesn't even exceed 4gb. I hope someone could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I will give a general answer about what you may and may not store on iCloud, since you didn't specify what data is important to you.

---

### What you can store in iCloud:

**Photos** 
If iCloud Photo Library is activated you can check the option to `optimize phone storage`, which will offload your photos and store them on iCloud. Therefore, when you want to view them in full resolution you need a internet connection (be careful with cellular data, especially for videos).

**Documents** 
You can save documents (e.g. pdfs, pages/word docs,...) in iCloud Drive, with the *Files* app (requires iOS 11).

**Music** 
If you use a streaming service (e.g. Apple Music, Spotify,...) the music files themselves can be streamed (as the name implies) and therefore don't need to be stored locally.

---

### What you can't store in iCloud:

**Apps** 
You can't store the app on iCloud. The same is true for most app data (exception to this are e.g. pages/numbers/... documents)

**System** 
Quite obviously, iOS itself needs to be stored locally.

---

To get an overview of what is using your memory head over to `preferences` -> `general` -> `iPhone-storage`.

Note that some apps (e.g. WhatsApp) store their data in the app and all your chats and their media will be shown as app data.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, it’s the other way around. You *can’t* have all your iCloud files stored on the phone as well; it will download them as and when they’re needed. (Photos are an exception to this; iCloud Photo Library *will* keep all your photos on the phone unless you tell it not to.)